# Using DispatchGroup in onAppear

Tags: swiftui, cloudkit

What I am trying to achieve is:
1) fetch records from cloudkit (excluding assets)
2) randomly select 3 recordIDs from those fetched records
3) fetch the full 3 records from cloudkit (including assets).

The issue that I'm struggling with is making sure that 1, 2, & 3 begin and are completed one after the other.

```
    //...
    .onAppear(){

            let group = DispatchGroup()

            // MARK: - 1) fetch from CloudKit - excluding CKAsset
            CloudKit.fetch() {(result) in
                group.enter() // moving group.enter() above CloudKit.fetch() locks everything up
                switch result {
                case .success(let newItem):
                    self.array.append(newItem)
                    group.leave()
                case .failure(let err):
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            // MARK: - 2) randomly select 3 records
            group.wait() // doesn't actually wait as this is executed before group.enter()
            self.array.shuffle()
            let firstSelection = self.array[0].recordID!
            let firstSelection = self.array[1].recordID!
            let firstSelection = self.array[2].recordID!

            // MARK: - 3) fetch recordID from CloudKit - includes CKAsset
            CloudKit.fetchRecord(recordID: self.array[0]) {(result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let newItem):
                    self.arrayRandomlySelected.append(newItem)
                case .failure(let err):
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            // run for remaining 2 records and move to next view when done
    }
```

I tried using `DispatchGroup()` but `group.wait()` gets called before `group.enter()`. Am I using `DispatchGroup()` correctly or should I be trying something else?

Comment: If you’re going to use dispatch group, you need `group.enter` _before_ you call `CloudKit.fetch()`. But this method is asynchronous for a reason and you shouldn’t block the main thread, waiting for it. You never should block the main thread.

Comment: The logic of provided code will result in crash even when executed synchronously and linear, because at 1) it fetches one item, but at 2) extracts 3, so `self.array[1]` result in crash. Would you update with corrected logic? I have a solution for DispatchGroup.

Comment: @Asperi I've tested the function and confirmed that it does fetch all four records from cloudkit. The app should not crash if 1) is finished running before 2) begins.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your feedback. The issue is if `group.enter` is put before `CloudKit.fetch()` is called then the whole app gets blocked. Is there a better solution in order to get the desired effect?

Comment: Put the code for steps 2 and 3 in a function and then call that function in the completion handler of `fetch` in step 1.